# I wanna know how to include a loop into a multiple choice quiz

Tags: python

```
begin = raw_input('would you like to start')
if begin == 'yes':
    print 'A) awesome'
    print 'B) pretty awesome'
    print 'C) you dont even know'
    print ''
    test = raw_input('How awesome is hayden?: ')
    if test == 'B' or test == 'b':
        print 'correct'
    else:
        if test == 'A' or test == 'a' or test == 'C' or test == 'c':
            print 'incorrect'
```

Detail: once user inputs an incorrect answer then the program ends or hits an error after second answer. I wanna loop so after they input "c" or "b" it will ask for another guess or they can answer again. Help please?

Comment: use `while True` to create `loop` and `break` to leave that loop.

Comment: use `test.lower()` to compare only with `a`, `b`, `c`. And you can check `if test in ['a', 'c']:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `while True` to create loop and `break` to leave loop.

```
while True:

    test = raw_input('How awesome is hayden?:').lower()

    if test == 'b':
        break

    print 'incorrect'

print 'correct'
```

Answer (score 3):

This is one of those places where I really wish python had an `until` loop structure... *BUT* it doesn't, so we make do with `while`.  There are a number of ways to write the logic -- Here's one:

```
test = None
while test.lower() != 'b':
    test = raw_input('How awesome is hayden?:')
    if test.lower() != 'b':
        print 'incorrect'
print 'correct'
```

---

Another option is to use 2 argument [`iter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#iter)...

```
def get_input():
    return raw_input('How awesome is hayden?:').lower()

for answer in iter(get_input, 'b'):
    print 'incorrect'
print 'correct'
```

This works because when you call `iter(function, sentinal)`, python will call `function` (yielding the result) until `function` returns `sentinal` at which point it stops yielding more values.

Answer (score 0):

So, what you want to use is a concept called a loop. In this case, you want the user to loop until they input a correct answer.

This type of loop is called a "while" loop -- you continue to loop while a certain condition has been met.

So, you could write a function like the following, which checks to see if a provided answer is in a list of correct answers:

```
def is_correct_answer(answer, correct_answers):
    return answer in correct_answers
```

Then you can write your program as follows:

```
answer = None
while not is_correct_answer(answer, ['B', 'b']):
    # your code for getting the answer
    # make sure to set the answer variable to their answer!
```

An important thing to note is to make sure that answer is initialized to not the correct answer to start off with, since the first thing the loop will do is evaluate the function, so if you started with answer containing 'B' or 'b', the loop would never run!

I'd also encourage you to read a beginner's guide to Python, since it seems like you're new! [Here is a good place to start.](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BeginnersGuide)

Comment: Note, mgilson and furas's suggestion to use .lower() is also a very good one!